Potential bug in answer display for a specific question
I recently answered a question. The question and the answer has no vote nor been marked as answered.
Anyway the question list layout shows it as answered:

While the answer is clearly not marked. Seems like a bug for this specific question to me.

There is a deleted accepted answer which you currently do not have the rep to see. It's current view is therefore a bug.

I've added the [tag:deleted-answers] to focus your question in light of the above.

Probably the actual bug is that the deleted answer stays accepted. Imagine a new answer being posted, that answer being accepted and then the previous accepted answer being undeleted. The universe might implode.

Other than the deleted answer still being marked accepted why is the deletion done by the community user when the answer is neither marked as spam nor rude / abusive.

@AbdulAzizBarkat There is at least one other answer by that user deleted at the same time. That combined with the deletion by Community indicates these posts were deleted by staff/an automated process, not by moderators. Could be genAI or could be some other type of fraud... possibly duplicate accounts or voting ring of some kind.

@TylerH so basically there's a bug (where deletion doesn't unaccept answers and potentially other stuff as well) in a tool the staff use and the post was deleted using that.
